# typeahead suggestions do not appear

Tags: typeahead.js

hello everyone I'm trying to use a small project and typeahead.js mine but it just does not work no matter what I do, I've re-written the code, removed other javascript libraries but nothing works, what can be?

My javascript

```
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery(function(){
var substringMatcher = function(strs) {
    return function findMatches(q, cb) {
        var matches, substringRegex;

        // an array that will be populated with substring matches
        matches = [];

        // regex used to determine if a string contains the substring `q`
        substrRegex = new RegExp(q, 'i');

        // iterate through the pool of strings and for any string that
        // contains the substring `q`, add it to the `matches` array
        $.each(strs, function(i, str) {
            if (substrRegex.test(str)) {
                // the typeahead jQuery plugin expects suggestions to a
                // JavaScript object, refer to typeahead docs for more info
                matches.push({ value: str });
            }
        });
        cb(matches);
    };
};

var colors = ["red", "blue", "green", "yellow", "brown", "black"];
jQuery('.typeahead').typeahead( {}, {source: substringMatcher(colors)} );
});
});
```

html

```
<input type="text" class="typeahead" data-provide="typeahead">
```

Comment: Post the code you've written - or post a jsFiddle of it.

Comment: Also specify which typeahead.js script you are using... there must be thousands of these kind of scripts out in the wild by now ;-)

Comment: i'm using twitter typeahead.js

Answer (score 0):

When you use

```
jQuery.noConflict();
```

you cannot use `$` anymore, as in

```
$.each(strs, function(i, str) {
```

that line should be

```
jQuery.each(strs, function(i, str) {
```

This solves the problem. Have a look at the jsbin:

http://jsbin.com/ratuho/1/

Comment: Did you take a look at the jsbin? It's working there.